# "Call to a member function append() on null" and "Undefined property: Google\Service\Sheets::$spreedsheets_values"

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

```
<?php
$time = time();
$name = $_GET['cname'];
$invoiceNumber = $_GET['invoice'];
$date = $_GET['date'];
$percentage = $_GET['percentage'];
$taxableValue = $_GET['taxableValue'];
$discount = $_GET['discount'];
$invoictotoal = $_GET['total'];
$sgst = $percentage*$taxableValue/100;
echo $discount;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
    $client->setAuthConfig('C:\Users\mitta\Desktop\Seagull\form\credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$client->addScope(Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);
$service = new Google\Service\Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
try{

    $spreadsheetId = '1H6EHEHGsHyRZTE-j8er9DrZjj-b9TkRg0p96K-h90Pc';
    $range = 'Form Responses 1';
    $valuetoinsert = [
        [$time,$name,$invoiceNumber,$date,$percentage,$invoictotoal,$taxableValue,$discount,$sgst,$sgst],
    ];
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'values' => $valuetoinsert
    ]);
    $params = [
        'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
    ];
    $inset = [
        "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
    ];
    $result = $service->spreedsheets_values->append(
        $spreadsheetId,
        $range,
        $body,
        $params
    );
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    printf($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I am getting this error on line 53 i.e; "$result = $service->spreedsheets_values->append(
$spreadsheetId,
$range,
$body,
$params
);"
I am getting the following error:

Warning: Undefined property: Google\Service\Sheets::$spreedsheets_values in D:\xamp\htdocs\form\insert.php on line 53

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function append() on null in D:\xamp\htdocs\form\insert.php:53 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xamp\htdocs\form\insert.php on line 53

Comment: You have a typo. Change `spreedsheets_values` to `spreadsheets_values`.

Comment: Iamblichus is correct, it seems that you have a typo in your function, change it to `spreadsheets_values` you may as well want to check the PHP example in this documentation: [`Spreadsheet.values.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)